# How to end edit mode connection from database without refreshing a page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, pdo

need your help on this.

I have 2 click event, one on table which is for add mode and one button which is on another table for update mode. These two mode has one input property, it changes value when I clicked for add and update. My problem is from update mode then to add click event, when I (button) submit the add value, the mode is still on update. It changes the existing value not adding another value to database.

How would I end the update mode to give way the add mode?

```
<form method="post" id="api_crud_form">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="h4">Add / Update Item</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">

            <button type="submit" name="button_action" id="button_action-insert" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control" value="Insert">Save</button>

            <button type="submit" name="button_action" id="button_action-update" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control" value="Update">Update</button>

          <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
          <input type="hidden" name="order_id" id="order_id" />
          <input type="text" name="tran_id" id="tran_id" value="<?php echo $tran_id; ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="tran_amount" id="tran_amount" />

            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="insert" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" name="tran_quantity" id="tran_quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity here" autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" class="input form-control" readonly/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" name="product_price" style="text-align: right;" id="product_price" class="input form-control" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</form>
```

**Here is JS code**

```
$('#api_crud_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if($('#tran_quantity').val() == '') {

        alert("Enter Quantity");
    } else if ($('#tran_quantity').val() == '0') {

        alert("Enter a valid number!");
    } else if ($('#product_description').val() == '') {

        alert("You have not selected an item yet.");
    } else if ($('#product_price').val() == '') {

        alert("You have not selected an item yet.");
    } else {

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data) {

                fetch_data();
                $('#api_crud_form')[0].reset();
                $('#apicrudModal').modal('hide');
                if(data == 'insert') {
                    alert("Item inserted successfully!");
                }

                if(data == 'update') {
                    alert("Item updated successfully");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What decides if it should add or update? Is it the "action" field? I don't see that field changing anywhere?

Comment: the button property...

Comment: fetch_data();
  $('#button_action-update').hide();
  $('#button_action-insert').show();

  function fetch_data()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#fetch').html(data);
      }
    })
  }

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: One major issue is that you aren't handling button presses, at least not in the code you provided. You are handling a "submit" event of "api_crud-form". Both of your buttons do the same thing, submit that form and reload the page you are on. Do some research on event handling in jquery before you dig yourself deeper by writing more code.

Comment: actually, both buttons does there job, it can add and update value to database. Especially when I do the add first then update but when I first do update the existing value then try to add another value the mode on the update, it should be add.

Comment: @KevinWelch - Why is it a "major issue" that the OP is handling the form submission instead of the button presses? The buttons only do one thing, submitting the form.

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code that actually makes the decision if the code should update or insert? And again _edit your question_ to include the JS you wrote as a comment. Where is it located? When is it executed?